# How do I log parameters from custom containers in my Vertex AI pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

When using custom containers to train models in my pipeline, I want a way to log parameters. I don't see this documented yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a way to log parameters

Do you mean to output parameters from a custom container component?
Here's the latest doc for creating custom container component: https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/author-a-pipeline/components/#3-custom-container-components